# Set Minimum Date & Maximum date in SharePoint Date Time control

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, office-365

I have a start date & end date controls in SharePoint list.

Both listing current month dates.

If I select a start date in October, the end date should list dates after the start date, instead of current month date.

How can we achieve this functionality, where the selected value in End Date field is always greater than the Start Date value?

Comment: Showing dates only after the start date will be complex and will require some good scripts. Instead you can go for simple Jquery validation to check if End Date is greater than Start Date.